# How to declare person object, with string after I split it using toSplit() method?

Tags: java

I made the strings for itself, like:

```
johnName = parts[0]
johnSurname = parts[1]
.
.
.
```

**But what if I had 100 people instead of 3**? So how do I put the String array values to an object?

```
String text = "John.Davidson/05051988/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011968/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";
    String[] parts = text.split("[./ ]+" );

    String johnIme = parts[0];
    String johnPrezime = parts[1];
    String johnDatum = parts[2];
    String johnMesto = parts[3];

    String michaelIme = parts[4];
    String michaelPrezime = parts[5];
    String michaelDatum = parts[6];
    String michaelMesto = parts[7];

    String ivanIme = parts[8];
    String ivanPrezime = parts[9];
    String ivanDatum = parts[10];
    String ivanMesto = parts[11];


    Person john = new Person(johnIme, johnPrezime, datumJohn, johnMesto);
    Person michael = new Person(michaelIme,michaelPrezime,datumMichael ,michaelMesto);
    Person ivan = new Person(ivanIme,ivanPrezime,datumIvan ,ivanMesto);
```

> Person:
>    Ime: John
>    Prezime: Davidson
>    Datum: 1988-05-05
>    Mesto: Belgrade
>
> Person:
>    Ime: Michael
>    Prezime: Barton
>    Datum: 1968-01-01
>    Mesto: Krakov
>
> Person:
>    Ime: Ivan
>    Prezime: Perkinson
>    Datum: 1986-05-23
>    Mesto: Moscow

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please visit the [tour] to see how Stack Overflow flow and check [ask] to improve your question. [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others, that shows how you try to read multiple people entries and what is the error/exception you get when you try to do so.

Comment: If the format of the string is always going to be like `Name.Surname/DoB/Location` separated by spaces, you can use a [regex](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html). And since you have a variable number of people, I would suggest creating a collection of `Person` objects, rather than tracking each one as an individual variable

Comment: Yes, but how do i put the values into object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use a loop and an array of `Person` (or a `List<Person>` if you prefer):

```
// ASSERTION: parts.length % 4 == 0
Person[] people = new Person[parts.length / 4];
int peopleIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 4) {
    people[peopleIndex++] = new Person(parts[i], parts[i + 1], parts[i + 2], parts[i + 3]);
}
```

I suppose you don't even really need `peopleIndex`:

```
// ASSERTION: parts.length % 4 == 0
Person[] people = new Person[parts.length / 4];
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 4) {
    people[i / 4] = new Person(parts[i], parts[i + 1], parts[i + 2], parts[i + 3]);
}
```

Using a `List<Person>`:

```
// ASSERTION: parts.length % 4 == 0
List<Person> people = new LinkedList<>(); // Or new ArrayList<>(parts.length / 4), or...
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 4) {
    people.push(new Person(parts[i], parts[i + 1], parts[i + 2], parts[i + 3]));
}
```